# Rounding up to next significant figure

Tags: php

I need to round up any integer between 1 and infinity in php to the next significant figure (though in practice I'm unlikely to need to round up infinity, so will be happy to settle on reasonable internal limits) eg:

```
$x <= 10 ? $x = 10 
10 < $x <= 100 ? $x = 100  
100 < $x <= 1000 ? $x = 1000
```

etc.

Round / ceil etc don't seem to do the job quite as planned.  A pointer towards the correct algorhythm (or function?) would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function my_ceil($in) {
        if($in == 1) return $in;
        if($in == pow(10, strlen($in)-1)) return $in;
        return pow(10, strlen($in));
}

echo my_ceil(11); //100
echo my_ceil(10); //10
```

Comment: Thanks for this - this is the answer I've accepted, as it seems the most straightforward.

Comment: It does not work for some values, including `1`: `echo my_ceil(1); // 1` but it must be `10` according to the question. Also it does not deal with invalid inputs, especially strings and floats can easily render it useless.

Comment: Actually everything below 1 as well, e.g. -100, then strings `'+100'`, then the `INF` number and numbers that become expressed in scientific E notation won't work as well.

Comment: @hakre the requirement was `any integer between 1 and infinity` but then `will be happy to settle on reasonable internal limits` but yeah sure, I'll edit for `1`. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

i think this method will fix your problem:

```
function n($nr, $p = 10) {
    if($nr <= $p) {
        return $p;
    }

    return n($nr, $p*10);
}
```

heres the result:

```
echo n(1);
//output 10

echo n(232);
//output 1000

echo n(89289382);
//output 100000000
```

Comment: Interesting solution.  Is there an overhead in using a recursive function?

Comment: @Christian Mayne: Yes, recursion has the overhead of an additional function call per each recursion. This calculation does actually not need recursion, one variable does the job already, so iteration is preferable. And again calculation often is more preferable than iteration - but not always possible (or not always faster/more straight forward).

Answer (score 2):

```
$x = pow(10,floor(log10($x)) + (floor(log10($x)) == log10($x) && $x!=1 ? 0:1) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
echo ceil($x / pow(10, strlen($x))) * pow(10, strlen($x));
```

Only works when `$x` is an integer, but you say in your question that that is indeed the case, so there's no issue (unless you try to later use it with numbers containing decimals).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php
function nextSignificantFeature($number){
    $upper = pow(10, strlen($number));
    return $number == $upper/10 ? $number : $upper;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is the infinity number in PHP, so the implementation should deal with it as you wrote any number from 1 up to infinity [Demo](http://codepad.org/WQjGfXKf):

```
<?php

function n($number) {
    if ($number < 1) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Number must be greater or equal 1.');
    }
    if ($number === INF) {
        return INF;
    }

    $p = 10;
    while($number > ($p*=10));
    return $p;
}

echo n(1), "\n";
//output 10

echo n(232), "\n";
//output 1000

echo n(89289382), "\n";
//output 100000000

echo n(INF), "\n";
// output INF

echo n(-INF), "\n";
// throws exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Number must be greater or equal 1.'
```

This example does the iterative calculation in PHP userland code. There are some math functions in PHP that can do it inline like [`pow`](http://php.net/pow).